# Multiple thunderbird users using same local directory

Tags: thunderbird, email

I have two users "tramp" and "office" on my desktop, and I want to run thunderbird from both users(I trust both users). I dont have enough disk space, so I want both the users to use the same local directory. Is this possible?

I googled and found two solutions, but both dont seem to work:

--> solution 1 with users "default" and "newbie"

```
sudo addgroup default-thunderbird
sudo usermod -a -G default-thunderbird default
sudo usermod -a -G default-thunderbird newbie
cp -R ~/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird.backup
chgrp -R default-thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird
chmod g+rw ~/.mozilla/thunderbird
find ~/.mozilla/thunderbird -type d -exec chmod g+x \{\} \;
```

And then, with Thunderbird not running, newbie could run:

```
mv ~/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird.old
ln -s ~default/.mozilla/thunderbird ~/.mozilla/thunderbird
```

The above solution gives me a permission error and even if I change permissions, the settings are not picked up.

--> solution 2

```
gksu -u default thunderbird
```

The command just exits without opening thunderbird and without giving any error.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you move your profile folder outside the home folder, to a location that does not depend on the user that logs in. Then you share the same profile folder for both users.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the home file structure and if we say now the profile folder is on user's office account, then you could probably share this folder with other user(s).